Problemas con guardado de datos, desde MySQL a MariaDB
pues resulta que cambiamos una base de datos MySQL, a MariaDB.
El problema, es que tengo problemas para guardar la información hacia la base de datos.
Primero, obtengo la información desde una URL, lo convierto a JSONObject y lo trabajo desde ahi. Este es un fragmento de esa información:
{"localidad_nombre":"REÑACA","local_id":"7784","comuna_nombre":"VIÑA DEL MAR","local_nombre":"ESSENTIALMED"}

Como se puede apreciar, mucho uso de Ñ en este caso.
En la base de datos MySQL, la información se guarda correctamente:

Pero al momento de realizar lo mismo, con las mismas configuraciones hacia MariaDB, ocurre lo siguiente:

Cuál puede ser el problema? He probado de todo con los collations, ya que pensé que ese era problema. Agregué un filtro, para corregir errores en caso de que los hubiera, pero nada, sigue guardandose erroneamente en la base de datos.
Incluso revisé la función que guarda los datos, y esa función recibe bien los datos, pero quedan mal guardados en la base de datos.

Este es el resultado, si lo hago directamente.

La única diferencia que tengo, es desde el origen, en donde la Ñ, aparece como carácter unicode.


Resultado del Show Create:
CREATE TABLE `farmacia` (
  `id_local` int NOT NULL,
  `comuna_minsal` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_comuna` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `comuna_sii` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_local` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `localidad` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_localidad` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_apertura_normal_semana` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_apertura_normal_sabado` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_apertura_normal_domingo` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_cierre_normal_semana` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_cierre_normal_sabado` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_cierre_normal_domingo` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_apertura_turno` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora_cierre_turno` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lunes_viernes` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `sabado` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitdud` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitud` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `domingo` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `turno` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci


¿Qué usas para volcar los datos en la nueva BD? ¿Es código PHP? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta. Muestra también el SHOW CREATE TABLE nombreDeLaTabla; en el nuevo entorno.

Use el mismo tipo de configuración que mysql, agregue el .jar ya que es java. La única diferencia es en la base de datos, el código no tiene diferencias. Ahora deje la consulta que me solicitaste, y puedo ver que la tabla cambio de collation a UTF8, pero no asi las columnas. Y yo habia usado el ALTER TABLE tu_tabla CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci; para cambiarlo.

Probé a cambiar una columna completa y mandar los datos de nuevo, pero es el mismo caso.

Y MariaDB no cuenta con algun adicional como para cargar directamente la base de datos desde un archivo .sql tal como lo hace MySQL ?

Encontré una posible solución para la base de datos.
El charset y el collation, los modifiqué a los siguientes:

Posteriormente, la función de guardado, en este caso mi gramod_farmacia, lo borré y lo volví a agregar, esto para que tomara la nueva configuración de la base de datos.
Ya con esto, y sin necesidad de cambiar la tabla directamente, guarda los datos bien. Pero es recomendable realizar el cambio en las tablas, para que no haya problemas de datos.

y acá el resultado del cambio en los datos:


Debes usar MODIFY para cambiar CHARACTER SET y COLLATE. Si no te lo hace aplicándolo a toda la tabla, entonces puedes atacar directamente a la(s) columna(s). Revisa la documentación. Por lo demás, conviene que no haya disparidad en una misma tabla.

Es MariaDB compatible con UTF8 y sus variantes cierto? Hay manera de comprobar eso?

Lo es. Aquí puedes ver los que son soportados.

Y lo puedes verificar también ejecutando las consultas SHOW CHARACTER SET; y SHOW COLLATION; respectivamente.
